# How to call excel add-ins from python

Tags: python, excel-addins

Is there a way to call Excel add-ins from python? In my company there are several excel add-ins that are available, they usually provide direct access to some database and make additional calculations.

What is the best way to call those functions directly from python?

To clarify, I'm NOT interested in accessing python from excel. I'm interested in accessing excel-addins from python.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a simple solution. [This might help you get started.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169877/load-excel-add-in-using-win32com-from-python)

Comment: Hi. Have you found a way to do this? Could you please share the solution? Thanks

Comment: Is this for an interactive or non-interactive usage? (i.e. is there a screen desktop open and a regular used logged in, or you wanna run as a scheduled task)

Answer (score 7):

There are at least 3 possible ways to call an Excel add-in, call the COM add-in directly or through automation.

Microsoft provide online documentation for it's Excel interop (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel). Whilst it's for .NET, it highlights the main limitations. You cannot directly call a custom ribbon (which contains the add-in). This is intended to protect one add-in from another. (*Although you can install/ uninstall add-in*).

**COM add-in**
You can call the COM add-in directly using win32com.client. However you can only run methods that are visible to COM.  This means you may have to alter the add-in. See a C# tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2019.

Once the method is exposed, then it can be called in Python using [win32com.client](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). For example:

```
import win32com.client as win32

def excel():
    # This may error if Excel is open.
    return win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

xl = excel()
helloWorldAddIn = xl.COMAddIns("HelloWorld") # HelloWorld is the name of my AddIn.
#app = helloWorldAddIn.Application 
obj = helloWorldAddIn.Object # Note: This will be None (null) if add-in doesn't expose anything.
obj.processData() # processData is the name of my method
```

**Web scraping**
If you're able to upload your add-in to an office 365 account. Then you could preform web scraping with a package like Selenium. I've not attempted it. Also you'll most likely encounter issues calling external resources like connection strings & http calls.

**Automation**
You can run the add-in using an automation package. For example [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can write code to control the mouse & keyboard to simulate a user running the add-in. This solution will mean you shouldn't need to update existing add-ins.

A very basic example of calling add-in through automation:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time

def openFile():    
    path = "C:/Dev/test.xlsx"
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    os.startfile(path)
    time.sleep(1)

def fullScreen():    
    pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'up')
    time.sleep(1)

def findAndClickRibbon():    
    pyautogui.moveTo(550, 50)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1)

def runAddIn():    
    pyautogui.moveTo(15, 100)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(1)

def saveFile():    
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
    time.sleep(1)

def closeFile():    
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'f4')
    time.sleep(1)

openFile()
fullScreen()
findAndClickRibbon()
runAddIn()
saveFile()
closeFile()
```

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/excel) list some of the available packages to work with Excel and Excel files. You might find the answer to your question there.

As a summary, here are the name of some of the listed packages:

> 1. openpyxl - Read/Write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm files
> 2. xlrd - Extract data from Excel spreadsheets (.xls and .xlsx, versions 2.0 onwards) on any platform
> 3. xlsxwriter - Write files in the Excel 2007+ XLSX file format
> 4. xlwt - Generate spreadsheet files that are compatible with Excel 97/2000/XP/2003, OpenOffice.org Calc, and Gnumeric.

And especially this might be interesting for you:

> ExPy - ExPy is freely available demonstration software that is simple to install. Once installed, Excel users have access to built-in Excel functions that wrap Python code. Documentation and examples are provided at the site.

Comment: You misread my question. What I'm interested in is the opposite. I want to access excel-addins from python and NOT python from excel

Comment: Huh! It seems that nobody might have a clue! See the following link, almost similar question was asked few month back and still no answer! https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3zv5ai/accessing_excel_addin_through_pythonwin_com/

Comment: @Nickpick, were you ever able to figure this out? I am looking to do the same thing and I cannot seem to find a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: The answer is not relevant. Please delete it and upvote is confusing